# Formato Hora superior a 1 día en Python

Tags: python, datetime, horas

Cuento con una tabla en Excel que indica las horas trabajadas de ciertos funcionarios. A la hora de traspasar el total a Python, las horas toman el formato de 24 horas, es decir, una suma que de como total 25 horas, se muestra como 1
Actualmente importo el total de la siguiente forma:

```
Total = Funcionarios['TOTAL'][i].strftime('%H:%M')
```

No he encontrado la solución a mi problema ya que no encuentro el formato correcto que reemplace el '%H:%M'

Comment: Entonces, tal vez no te conviene que la columna de excel sea formato fecha. Tu error se debe a que estás convirtiendolo en una fecha y hora, no en cantidad de horas trabajadas. Puedo darte una respuesta, pero insisto en que debe de haber otro tipo de dato en excel que no sea fecha y hora.

Comment: la columna en cuestión esta en formato hora '[h]:mm:ss', de esta manera me muestra la cantidad total de horas trabajadas

Comment: Pues viendo que usas y como usas el método strftime (que pertenece al objeto datetime del modulo datetime), te diría que excel o el modulo de Python que usas para leer el libro de trabajo está interpretando esa celda como una fecha.

Comment: y como puedo obtener el dato de la forma que quiero?

Comment: Tienes tres opciones. Puedes convertir el tipo de dato de la columna a uno más cercano, convertir el tipo de dato a cadena y hacer un código extra para obtener lo que buscas o puedes obtener a partir de la fecha un timedelta (que es el objeto en Python que sería el que necesitas) Cual prefieres?

Comment: Pero una pregunta, que modulo usas para leer el archivo?

Comment: @Dante S. uso pandas

Comment: @Dante S. obtener el formato a partir de timedelta, esa seria mi opcióin xd

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicación

El problema se debe a que pandas (o, probablemente, el modulo usado para cargar el archivo xlsx) interpreta los campos como fechas y horas. No parece existir un tipo de dato en excel que coincida con lo que buscas. Si lo que buscas es convertir estos objetos en algo que almacene las horas, minutos y segundos, lo mejor que puedes hacer es convertirlos en objetos [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)o [crear tu propio objeto](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-5/programacion-orientada-a-objetos).

#### El objeto timedelta

El objeto timedelta es un objeto especial del modulo datetime que representa la diferencia entre fechas y horas.

Entre otras pocas cosas, este objeto provee un método para obtener los segundos totales: [total_seconds](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds). Es muy probable que con este método puedas hacer los calculos que necesitas.

Si aun así requieres los minutos y/o las horas, tendrás que usar matematica. Donde dt es un objeto timedelta, las siguientes formulas te servirán:

```
dt.total_seconds() / 3600 ---> 3600 es la cantidad de segundos en una hora. Esto devuelve un numero flotante que sería la cantidad de horas trabajadas.
dt.total_seconds() / 60 ---> 60 es la cantidad de segundos en un minuto. Esto te devolverá un número flotante con la cantidad de minutos trabajados.
```

#### Nuestro propio objeto

Un ejemplo de un objeto propio puede ser uno que tenga el unico objetivo de almacenar los datos.

```
class WorkedHours:
    # esto se llama cuando se crea una instancia del objeto, es decir, haces WorkedHours(...)
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds

    # esto se llama cuando usas la función repr. Esto también es llamado por la función str cuando el método __str__ no está implementado.
    def __repr__(self):
        return ":".join((str(self.hours), str(self.minutes).zfill(2), str(self.seconds).zfill(2)))
```

*Advertencia* Este objeto no regula los datos que se le ingresan. Por ejemplo podrías decirle que la persona hizo 1 hora y 100 minutos y no se quejaría. Si quieres que de error, eso lo tendrás que implementar vos mismo.

#### Solución 1. De fecha a timedelta:

Primero vamos a crear una función que reciba una fecha y hora y se encargue de convertirlo a timedelta:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# desde la fecha 31/12/1899 es cuando excel empieza la cuenta para calcular otras fechas
start_date = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 31)

def datetime_to_timedelta(fecha):
    # Si fecha hace referencia a un objeto time...
    # esto va a ser verdadero cuando las horas trabajadas sumen menos de un dia
    if(isinstance(fecha, datetime.time)):
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=fecha.hour, minutes=fecha.minute, seconds=fecha.second)
    else:
        # aquí restamos a fecha la fecha en la que inicia a contar excel para calcular la fecha ingresada
        # esto nos dará un timedelta 
        return fecha - start_date


# el parametro converters nos dice que convertidores aplicaremos a cada columna especifica
# en forma de diccionario de {columna 1: convertidor, columna 2: convertidor, ...}
df = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", header=None, converters={0:datetime_to_timedelta})

print(df)
```

Para un excel del tipo:

| A |
| --- |
| 13:00:00 |
| 16:00:00 |

El dataframe resultante es:

```
                0
0 0 days 13:00:00
1 1 days 16:12:23
```

Incluso puedes obtener directamente una columna con el total de segundos trabajados modificando ligeramente la función datetime_to_timedelta:

```
def datetime_to_timedelta(fecha):
    # Si fecha hace referencia a un objeto time...
    # esto va a ser verdadero cuando las horas trabajadas sumen menos de un dia
    if(isinstance(fecha, datetime.time)):
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=fecha.hour, minutes=fecha.minute, seconds=fecha.second).total_seconds()
    else:
        # aquí restamos a fecha la fecha en la que inicia a contar excel para calcular la fecha ingresada
        # esto nos dará el total de segundos entre las dos fechas
        return (fecha - start_date).total_seconds()
```

#### Solución 2. De fecha a WorkedHours

Esta solución está basada en la solución 1. Te recomiendo leerla antes de leer esta.

Podemos usar la función original y modificarla para los objetos WorkedHours creado por nosotros. Ahora la función convertidora será así (ojo, le cambié el nombre):

```
def datetime_to_workedhours(fecha):
    if(isinstance(fecha, datetime.time)):
        return WorkedHours(hours=fecha.hour, minutes=fecha.minute, seconds=fecha.second)
    else:
        dt = fecha - start_date
        extra_hours, extra_seconds = divmod(dt.seconds, 3600)
        
        hours = dt.days*24 + extra_hours
        minutes, seconds = divmod(extra_seconds, 60)
        
        return WorkedHours(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Como habrás notado, uso la función divmod, que se encarga de dividir dos numeros y devolvernos una tupla del estilo `(a//b, a%b)` o sea `(cociente, resto)`

#### Antes de continuar...

No se nada de excel, y no logré convertir con exito de manera automatizada la columna a texto (me salen numeros decimales). Por lo que las siguientes dos soluciones están sin probar y asumen que de alguna forma convertiste con exito el tipo de dato de la columna a texto. Si no encuentras la manera (o no quieres) de convertir la columna a texto (por cierto, puedes lograrlo programáticamente), entonces no es necesario que leas la siguiente solución.

#### Solución 3. De cadena a timedelta/WorkedHours

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def text_to_timedelta(horas):
    # asumo que la cadena SIEMPRE va a estar en formato 'HH:MM:SS',
    # separo la cadena cada ":",
    # recorro la lista resultante con comprensión de generador para convertir cada parte en entero y desempaco el generador.
    hours, minutes, seconds = (int(part) for part in horas.split(":"))
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
    
df = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", header=None, converters={0:text_to_timedelta})

print(df)
```

Para lograr lo mismo pero creando un objeto WorkedHours, solo hay que cambiar esta linea:

```
return datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```

Por esta:

```
return WorkedHours(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```

#### Cierre

Me disculpo por dar una respuesta tan larga, pero espero haberlo compensado habiendote ayudado y haciendo que hayas aprendido algo nuevo. Espero sirva c:

Comment: ¿No sería mejor usar división entera (//) para convertir segundos a minutos y horas?

Comment: Sinceramente, no entiendo tu comentario @CandidMoe, haces referencia a una parte concreta de la respuesta? Con lo poco que entiendo te digo esto: recuerda que es mejor mantener la presición. Por ejemplo si haces 3660//3600, obtendrás 1 hora, en lugar de la hora y un minuto. O te refieres a usar propiedades en el objeto WorkedHours? Gracias por tu aporte c: